# how and when to put asp.net code in CMS

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I tried CMS (Dotnetnuke), created pages and stuff in it but one thing that I don't understand is that if I need something more complex like creating and running joins, queries, functions then I am gonna need my asp.net c#'s coding at some or many places. How do I integrate that code etc into my created CMS system via Dotnetnuke.

like code:

```
Select name, class from tbl1 inner join tbl2 ON tbl.name  tbl2.name;
```

or any other code?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of free/paid modules that you can download for DotNetNuke that can help you accomplish simple tasks like Forms (http://dnnfnl.codeplex.com/) and just displaying table data(http://www.indoolab.com/Default.aspx).

If you want customized data display and user interaction, you'll need to create a module (a user control that is designed to work with DNN). DNN's website is the best place for video training, but you'll find ton's of resources online (http://www.dnnsoftware.com/Training).  Each CMS will have its own way of integrating code, so I can't speak to the others.